# Push real data from flask python app to angular

Tags: python, angular, flask

I have flask server which serves angular frontend, using rest api.
I want to add push mechanism from the server to client for handling real time data.

I try use flask socketio for python and socket.io-client in angular but data isn't emitted
please note that I try to add socket io to the main app flask

Server:

```
app = create_app()
socketioR.__init__(app, cors_allowed_origins="*",logger=True, engineio_logger=True,log_output=True)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('runserver', Server(host='localhost', port=settings.SYSTEM_PORT, threaded=True))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
    socketioR.run(app, debug=True)
```

emit function:

```
def send_data():
    try:
        socketioR.send('message', {'data': 42}, namespace='/', broadcast=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

angular client:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import  io from "socket.io-client";
// import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PushService {

    public message$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject('');
  private socket: any;
  constructor() {
    try {
      this.socket = io('http://localhost:8119', {
        extraHeaders: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
        }
      });
      this.socket.on('connect_error',(message: any)=>
        console.log(message))
    }
    catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex)
    }
    this.getNewMessage()
  }



  public getNewMessage(){
    this.socket.on('message', (message: any) =>{
      this.message$.next(message);
    });

    return this.message$.asObservable();
  };

}
```

in the server the bellow logs repeated:

```
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2022 11:45:22] "OPTIONS /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O8BLMRO HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2022 11:45:22] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O8BLMRO HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

in angular client this error is raised by connection - parser error:

```
Error: server error
    at Socket.onPacket (socket.js:317:1)
    at Emitter.emit (index.mjs:136:1)
    at Polling.onPacket (transport.js:105:1)
    at callback (polling.js:118:18)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Polling.onData (polling.js:121:53)
    at Emitter.emit (index.mjs:136:1)
    at Request.onLoad (polling.js:365:18)
    at xhr.onreadystatechange [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYreadystatechange] (polling.js:301:26)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone.js:766:1)
```

Can anyone here let me know where Im going wrong? or supply any other different solution for this requirement?

Comment: no, it shoulf be added by in client side too

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by uninstalling and installing ‍‍`flask-SocketIO` package.